# In which case finally block does not execute in client side JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, try-catch

I was asked this question in an interview: In which case `finally` block doesn't execute in JavaScript.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal although the answers are similar, Java != JavaScript; the other question you point out is about Java.

Answer (score 3):

The `finally` block will always execute regardless of the outcome of the `try...catch` (i.e. regardless of whether an exception was thrown and/or handled). So, the only way that a `finally` will not get executed is if the code never reaches it (e.g. if there is an infinite loop in the code). You might also avoid the `finally` if the program is interrrupted / aborted altogether (e.g. if the user closes the window for browser-side JavasScript, or if the interpreter is interrupted for server-side JavaScript).

To give a specific example (don't try this in your browser):

```
var neverExits = function() {
  var x = 0;
  while (true) {
    x += 1;
  }
};

var example = function () {
   try {
     console.log('Entering try...'); // printed
     neverExits();
     console.log('Leaving try...');  // not printed
   } finally {
     console.log('Entering finally...'); // not printed
   }
};
```

The above example, if executed, will print out:

```
Entering try...
```

... and then it will make your browser completely unusable (so don't copy+paste).